# Where is Java 8 hiding?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, libgdx

This is probably a cliché question that was repeated a trillion times. But I'm asking here because I became fully and totally desperate and I need some pointers to continue.

I'm learning how to program games using LibGDX. I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b87Bz8mdlPE). The problem is the classic error:

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android
>   Package Builder' on project 'HelloWorld-android'.
>   com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version
>   52.0

I understand that this error means that some how, Eclipse is using Java 8 to compile, and an earlier version of Java to run, which is creating this incompatibility. But guess what? I don't even have Java 8 on my computer! I have:

1. Android SDK
2. Java 7u79
3. Eclipse Luna
4. LibGDX, that generates the project for me.

I don't understand why this is happening, so please assist and tell me why this would happen. Following are screenshots of Eclipse showing that everything is 1.7.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And yet I keep getting this error on right click -> Debug As -> Android Application:

[image]

What did I miss? Where is Java 52 coming from?

I would like to point out that the Desktop version of the game runs with not a single problem.

Thank you for any efforts. Please don't hesitate in asking for more information.

Comment: Did you try a clean/rebuild yet?

Comment: something you have was compiled for java 8 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi) you can't use that though

Comment: @Compass absolutely! Many times.

Comment: @zapl Thanks a lot for the link. I'll look into that link when I reach home. But I'd like to point out that I recreated the project a dozen of times.

Comment: You are correct about wrong version of compiler for the project. I would suggest checking the project facet if it's not set to Java8. If you are using Maven, you might want to check the `pom.xml` to confirm the `java.compiler` is set to correct version.

Comment: @zapl I spend another hour digging with this link and its possible solutions... nothing worked! I even added the parameter to the compilter `-target 1.7`, and that didn't help either. There's a Java 8 hiding somewhere. How can I find it? That's my main question!

Comment: @jmsweb I use Gradle actually (well, not me, libgdx creates a gradle project).

Comment: Android SDK 24.1.1 supports Java8. What's your Android SDK version?

Comment: @jmsweb It's 24.4.1... Do you think I should move to JDK 8? I just didn't do it because I heard many people saying it's not a good idea and has compatibility issues.

Comment: I haven't tried Android development but their requirement seem to specify Java8 for a reason. Maybe newer Android SDK included Lambda functions.

Comment: I think you have couple of options. You could download older Android SDK with support for Java7, or give in and install Java8. Please update us with your result.

Comment: @jmsweb Well I have to say that it had worked for one day... But then I did many different things and don't know what made it not work anymore. So I wouldn't be too sure that Android SDK is not compatible with Java 7. I'm planning to move to Java 8 today... I really gave up. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your code that requires Java 8.

> "Error running builder 'Android Package Builder'

means something in the android build tools, some of which are also written in Java, require Java 8 to run.

You'll have to install Java 8 so that it runs Eclipse & gradle. Java 8 can compile for Java 7, so you don't have to change the project to Java 8 (which would also mean the app would only work with Android N and above).

The safest bet is to remove all Java < 8 versions from your computer, that way you can't accidentally run with an older version. You'll have to update the "installed JREs", set the default (& especially the one in the gradle screen) to your Java 8 install, but keep the project's "Compiler compliance level" at 1.7.

Comment: Actually this gives me an idea... I will use the JDK 7 compiler, but I'll install the Java 8 runtime. If that doesn't work, I'm moving to Java 8 fully.

Comment: I gave up... I moved to Java 8 and it works now... I just hope I'll not have any back-compatibility issues when I set compliance level to an earlier version.